# how many number of objects and references are created?

Tags: java, string, object, heap-memory

I tired this below snippet and got the answer as 3 objects and 3 references.
But in the answer key said it is 4 objects and 3 references. I am confused if I was wrong or the answer key. Please someone help.

```
String str1=new String("Java"); //line 1
String str2=new String("GFT");  //line 2
String str3=str1;               //line 3 
str1=str1.concat(str2);         //line 4
str3=str2.toUpperCase();        //line 5
```

Explanation for my answer:

References: str1,str2,str3. So count of references=3.

Objects: Initially Object created count=0.

- Line 1 creates new object with value "Java" and reference "str1". Object created count=1.
- Line 2 creates new object with value "GFT" and reference "str2". Object created count=2.
- Line 3 creates new reference "str3" , it does not create new object & it points to object created in line 1 (str1).
- Line 4 creates new object with value "JavaGFT" and str1 now points to this object. Object created count=3.
- Line 5 has a value "GFT" as it is already present str3 now points to object created by str2 as str2 was created using new operator.( I verified if str2==str3 it returns true)
  So finally objects created count=3, references count=3.

Is this right?

Answer (score 3):

Since there are only three unique variable names, and each variable name is a reference, you're right that there are three references.

However, in Java (and many other languages), Strings are *immutable*, meaning that *any* operation on a String returns an entirely new String.

Your misconception seems to be with `String.toUpperCase()`. If the string is already completely uppercase, then this will return a new string which is equal to the original string. You can test this:

```
String strA = "ABC";
String strB = strA.toUpperCase();
// two objects that are technically different, though they look and act the same as each other

print(strA == strB);       // false - they are not the same string 
print(strA.equals(strB));  // true  - however, they are equal to each other
```

In Java this will hold true for *any Object** - the `==` check will compare the memory location of two references, and return `true` if they both point to the same location in memory. Meanwhile, `.equals()` can have customized behavior for an object. If not overridden, this falls back to the `==` check, but String overrides that behavior and returns `true` if the strings are identical.

So, in total, there are four objects created:

- `new String("Java")`
- `new String("GFT")`
- `str1.concat(str2)`
- `str2.toUpperCase()`  // identical to `str2`, but technically not the same object

---

*note: this does not hold true for primitives like `int`, `double`, etc., which do not have a `.equals()` method because they are not objects.

Comment: In my testing it seems like `toUpperCase()` will actually return `this` if it's already in uppercase. At least on OpenJDK 16. In other words, `strA == strA.toUpperCase()` is returning `true` for me.

Comment: Also, `new String("Java")` should, assuming `"Java"` isn't already interned, result in two objects being created. Meaning _potentially_ 6 objects are being created by the OP's example code.

Comment: But str2 was not created using = operator. It was created using new operator . So when I run it after performing toUpperCase(), str2==str3 returns true. This implies they are same objects right?

Comment: @Slaw Nitpicking about `new String("Java")`: The (interned) String representing the `"Java"` literal will not be created while executing the statements listed, but beforehand, most probably around class loading/initialization time.